# Where does Node.js install by default?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-12.04, npm

What folder does it install to on Ubuntu when I do:

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just type npm in the terminal. You will see the usage info and at the end npm version and folder where it is located in the sytem

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/npm
```